# Force https for my WordPress site...except for a specific sub-domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, encryption, https

I'm trying to figure out how I can exclude one specific sub-domain of my WordPress site from being forced to HTTPS.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # HTTPS by default
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This code perfectly works to enforce HTTPS. Now, I want my download.domain.com to stay in plain HTTP, not encrypted. I've tried many many things, and I didn't manage to get something which works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# HTTPS by default except for download.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=download.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This should do the trick.

When you are testing, be aware that browsers cache 301 redirects - so you might reject working solutions because your browser fools you. Make sure to open browser dev tools and disable request cache.

Comment: Nice answer Jan. +1

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot !! Be careful, small mistake in your code: no space after the "=" or you get an error 500.